# Replacing an auto generated column with a hyper link column in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to replace an `AutoGenerated` column with a new `DataGridHyperLinkColumn`, my code is this

```
private void dgv_University_AutoGeneratingColumns(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.PropertyName=="Web Address")
     {
         DataGridHyperlinkColumn col1 = new DataGridHyperlinkColumn();
         col1.Header = "Web Address";
         e.Column =col1;
     }
}
```

but I can't seem to generate the same contents of the column, can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create column in the `DataGridView` before setting `DataSource` or in the designer
Set `DataPropertyName = "Web Address";`

`DataGridView` will use your column for displaying data of `Web Address` column of your `DataSource`
And other columns will be generated as well

Comment: if i add a hyper link column before setting a data source then my column isn't accessible in the method this is how i am setting a data source for the grid
  ` OleDbDataAdapter da=new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from UniversityData",connection ) ;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);  `

Comment: Which method using that column and how?

Comment: the hyperlink column and the method which i am using to replace the column

Comment: You do not need to replace a column anymore. Because `DataGridView` will use column which was created and `DataPropertyName` was set

Comment: Check if value of `DataPropertyName` match a column name in the `DataSource`

Comment: `OleDbDataAdapter da=new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from UniversityData",connection ) ;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dgvUniversity.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView ();`

Comment: `dgvUniversity.ItemsSource` - this is wrong. `DataGridView` haven't property `ItemSource`